# Is there a known timeline for the deployment of the new CSS?

Tags: support, status-completed, design

Some [six to eight weeks ago](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+since+april+14+2015), Stack Exchange announced a programme to re-design the CSS and tweak the site styles throughout the network, including the [completely redesigned profile pages](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/). Since then, we've [made some big requests](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/can-we-have-a-font-which-harmonizes-better-with-mathjax) to come with the re-design, so we've remained "on deck" for some time. It seems, however, that the deck currently contains... just us.

> [List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

This isn't really a problem - I'm sure we would all rather they get it right than they get it out fast. However, I'm curious as to know how this matches with the [recently announced change in the width of the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1), which is admittedly a smaller change in the site design, but still. Moreover, I expect that the change in the sidebar is the reason for the [slight delay in the 2016 community ads thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads), since [the new ads will need to conform to the new width](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1#comment885010_272563).

So:

- In which order will the CSS redesign, the new sidebar, and the community ads thread launch?
- Are there known timelines for them? Or will the sidebar launch on par with everyone else on the 12th, with no fixed timeline for the CSS?

I don't mean to pressure the team, but since we're last on the line I thought it wouldn't be too much to ask politely :).

Comment: "_Are there known timelines for them ?_". Yes. They'll wrap it up in _another_ six to eight weeks :P

Comment: I've been waiting and waiting and waiting....... now wait for another eight weeks:/

Comment: CSS redesign is ten years in the future and always will be... (Apologies to the fusion energy community).

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/smashmouth/walkinonthesun.html second line of the chorus...

Comment: I made a quick [timeline](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wGcFA.png) of when other sites were updated (based solely on when the list on meta was edited). The endpoint is today, Jan. 8, and the first point is Apr. 14 of last year.

Comment: There is a nice gem in the [2015 Year in Review](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/year-in-review-2015/?cb=1) -- "Additionally, all sites were updated to use the Less preprocessor, polished for higher-resolution monitors and now have new profile pages." Me thinks they exaggerated or just totally forgot about us because we *still* don't have the new profiles. Of all the random changes they've been rolling out that have actually happened on our site, that is the *only* one I actually want and it's the only one we haven't gotten yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new CSS has been deployed... uh, sometime in the last week. The new sidebar went live on Tuesday. And the community ads thread should be coming shortly. (I don't have a more specific ETA than that, unfortunately.)

We did, however, forget to enable new user profiles when the CSS update happened. I flipped the relevant switches, so that's fixed up now. Sorry about that.

If you see any issues with the updated design, please report them here on meta with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [design](/questions/tagged/design) tags.

Comment: I *literally* just saw our new profiles work! Thank you -- of all the changes, this was the only one I was actually really excited to get!