# Was the new font incompletely implemented?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

As you all might have noticed, our posts appear in a brand new font since today ([as requested long ago](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7419/serif-fonts-like-chemistry-and-math). However, there are some places where the font has not been implemented, and this leads to some silly "design bugs". I took a screenshot of one of them (note the two different zeros), but I'm sure there are a bunch of other ones too. I think it is important to note that this "bug" (for lack of a better term) does not occur on e.g. [math.se], where the old font is kept for both the answer count and the vote count. Is this temporary? Accidental? Intentional?

[image]

In any case, I guess I'm requesting that the font be consistently implemented. If anyone objects, I'd like to hear so in the comments, or an answer to this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the vote count is deliberately styled with a sans-serif font. It looks fine on normal question pages like this one, since here it's surrounded by (and visually associated with) the up/down vote icons. But it does look kind of jarring in contexts (like question lists and review) where you can't vote, and so the buttons are not present.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yeah, but then the answer count should *also* retain the old style (note that this is the case on [math.se])